# Can I create an exception as a spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-bean

Can I create an spring bean which is a Java exception?

And then throw it multiple times ( lets say using different strings via setter)

Comment: I see no reason that a bean couldn't extend Exception. Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Also, throwing the same Exception instance multiple times will probably give you incorrect stack trace information. But it's possible (and a bad idea).

Comment: And if the message is updated via a setter, then it's not going to be thread safe.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes We can create. Sample code given below.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyCustomException myCustomException() {
        return new MyCustomException("This is a Spring-managed exception.");
    }
}

public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyCustomException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
 }
```

for Custom exception as below:

```
public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException {
public MyCustomException(String message) {
    super(message);
}

public void setCustomMessage(String message) {
    // This is a bit hacky, but demonstrates the concept
    this.setStackTrace(this.getStackTrace());
    this.initCause(null);
    this.suppressedExceptions.clear();
    super.fillInStackTrace();
    
    try {
        Field detailMessage = Throwable.class.getDeclaredField("detailMessage");
        detailMessage.setAccessible(true);
        detailMessage.set(this, message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to set custom message.", e);
    }
}
}
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public MyCustomException myCustomException() {
    return new MyCustomException("Initial message.");
}
}


@Service
public class SomeService {
@Autowired
private MyCustomException myCustomException;

public void someMethod() {
    myCustomException.setCustomMessage("New message.");
    throw myCustomException;
}
}
```

Comment: This is not good advice or even a good idea. This is not threadsafe at all. It introduces way more problems than the benefit of reusing the same instance could ever be.